# How to refresh ui of other view from one view both present inside different tabs in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, tabs

I am new to `backbone`, in my current project we are using `Backbone` and `Requirejs`.
There are 4 tabs say **A,B,C,D**. In tab **A** i save some data in db and in tab **D** the data that is saved from tab **A** should be displayed.So, i am calling the render method of tab **D** after save operation in tab **A** is completed.

When screen is loaded first time, all tabs load properly with proper data.
But when i save data from tab **A** and call render method of tab **D** it does not update ui.Problem is that, `render()`   is getting called with no errors but ui in tab **D** is not getting refreshed.

Following is my Dummy Code for tab A:

```
define(['jquery','backbone','underscore','views_jira/tabDView'],
    function($,Backbone,_,TabDView) 
    {
        var TabAView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tabDView:new TabDView(),
            render:function(){
                this.model.save(objectToSave,{
                        success: _.bind( this.saveSuccessCallback, this ),
                        error: _.bind( this.saveErrorCallback, this )
                    });
            }
        });


        saveSuccessCallback: function ( model, response ) {
                tabDView.render()
        },

        saveErrorCallback:function ( model, response ) {
        }
    }
);
```

Following is the code for tab D:

```
 define(['jquery','backbone','underscore','collections'],
    function($,Backbone,_,DataCollection) {
        var TabDView = Backbone.View.extend({
             el:'#myViewDivinHtmlBody'
            dataCollection:new DataCollection();
            render:function(){
                this.dataCollection.fetch({
                    success: _.bind(this.handleOpendTicketsSuccessCallback, this),
                    error: _.bind(this.handleOpendTicketsErrorCallback, this)
                });
            },
            handleOpendTicketsSuccessCallback:function(model, response, fetchOptions){
                this.$el.find('.mydiv').append(response);
            },
            handleOpendTicketsErrorCallback:function(model, response, fetchOptions){
                 console.log("Error in fetching the  tickets");
            } 

        });

        return TabDView;
    }
)
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong.
Note:there is no console error.

Comment: I don't see any code that adds `TabDView` element to DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Backbone Views need to be told which element of the DOM to attach to. If you don't specify this somehow, then `el` and `$el` are assigned to a detached `<div>` tag, not in the DOM. Thus rendering to it works with no errors, but is not visible.

Do you have a successful initial render with your views? If so, you must have attached them to a DOM element in some code not included in your sketch here. For example:

```
var tabAView = new TabAView({el: '#tabA'});
```

or possibly

```
tabAView.setElement('#tabA');
```

One way to preset it for all instances of the view create is:

```
var TabAView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#tabA',
    // etc
});
```

Whether the view is given an element at creation time or later, the DOM element should exist first. If the selector comes up empty, the `el` will again default to a detached `<div>`.

---

The punch-line is, when you create the reference to a new `TabDView` instance in your `TabAView` definition, make sure that it has it's reference set to an attached DOM element before rerendering. I would suggest the following in your `TabAView`:

```
saveSuccessCallback: function ( model, response ) {
    tabDView.setElement('#tabD');
    tabDView.render()
},
```

Comment: Yes actually i missed to put the line in my dummy code  where i assign el to the TabDView . Now i have edited  the question.

Comment: Actually your solution of tabDView.setElement ("#tabD") has worked.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. I've learned working with Backbone that when things don't seem to be working, but there are no console errors, the reason is very often a View whose `el` is not referring to what you think it is.

Comment: Yeah . . good to help the people on what we have learned. It gives pleasure. Thanx